# Moving from Windows to Mac...a few questions on data migration

Tags: migration

I was using Bootcamp on an iMac27 (2017) for a variety of reasons I decided to go back to using Mac natively. I was backing up all my data from Windows to 2 external RAID Drobo devices (5C and 5D).  My issue is that my original Windows bootcamp volume got corrupted so I have to do all my data migration from the Drobo devices which are formatted in NTFS. I can read and copy some of the data over to the Mac main HHD fine, but my issue is I can't write to any existing data on those drives.
Questions:
Is it true that I need to move the data on the NTFS volumes to another source, then format the Drobo volumes in a native Mac format? if so which Mac format is recommended? I see a number of them. The key data I'll be reading/writing from the Drobo is large Lightroom raw photo data (about 1.2TB)
anything Im missing?

Comment: If you are MacOS only then yes this is best. However if you are going to run Windows and only access Drobo from Windows then you could use Paragon's NTFS for Mac https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/# to write from macOS to NTFS

Answer (score 1):

macOS can read but not write NTFS natively.

There are freeware solutions to this, but I would recommend [Paragon's NTFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/) for trouble-free operation.

If you're accessing the Drobo over the network, then the Drobo itself should be responsible for handling read/write, not the Mac.

Comment: thanks. good tip on Paragon. that was so much easier than migrating all that data. worked well, Lightroom on Mac now sees and can read/write to my NTFS volumes! thanks again